# What does Hagrid eat?

Tags: harry-potter, food, hagrid

Motivated by a comment [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114560/what-are-the-dormice-for/114567?noredirect=1#comment277052_114567) ...

## What does Rubeus Hagrid eat (in canon)?

Presumably giants have quite different diets from humans: Grawp, for instance, living in the Forbidden Forest, seemed to be feeding himself on birds and other small animals, and probably never had cooked food. As a half-giant, is Hagrid's diet any different from that of a normal human? I assume he's not a vegetarian, at least. But what do we *know* about what he eats?

Any level of canon is acceptable, but no fanfiction.

Comment: For one thing, **kettles**. `'Givin' me advice on gettin' kelpies out of a well,' growled Hagrid, moving a half-plucked rooster off his scrubbed table and setting down the teapot. 'Like I don' know. An' bangin' on about some Banshee he banished. If one word of it was true, I'll eat my kettle.'`

Comment: ....Rock cakes.

Comment: He eats stoats - I'd say he'd be more than happy to eat dormice as well.

Comment: @DVK By that reasoning humans eat hats in real life.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I will honestly admit that I haven't the faintest idea what some of these foods are.

- **sausages**

  > The giant sat back down on the sofa, which sagged under his weight, and began taking all sorts of things out of the pockets of his coat: a copper kettle, a squashy package of sausages, a poker, a teapot, several chipped mugs and a bottle of some amber liquid which he took a swig from before starting to make tea. Soon the hut was full of the sound and smell of sizzling sausage. Nobody said a thing while the giant was working, but as he slid the first six fat, juicy, slightly burnt sausages from the poker, Dudley fidgeted a little. Uncle Vernon said sharply, 'Don't touch anything he gives you, Dudley'
  > (*PS, Ch 4, "The Keeper of the Keys"*)
- **mint humbugs**

  > Hagrid's coat seemed to be made of nothing but pockets – bunches of keys, slug pellets, balls of string, mint humbugs, tea-bags... finally, Harry pulled out a handful of strange-looking coins. (*PS, Ch 5, Diagon Alley*)
- **Ice Cream** (he got 2, and presumably Harry only ate 1)

  > 'I say, look at that man!' said the boy suddenly, nodding towards the front window. Hagrid was standing there, grinning at Harry and pointing at two large ice-creams to show he couldn't come in. ...
  > Harry was rather quiet as he ate **the ice-cream Hagrid had bought him (chocolate and raspberry with chopped nuts)**. (*PS, Ch 5*)
- **Hamburgers**

  > He bought Harry a **hamburger** and **they sat down on plastic seats to eat them**. Harry kept looking around. Everything looked so strange, somehow. (*PS, Ch 5*)
- **hams and pheasants**

  > There was only one room inside. Hams and pheasants were hanging from the ceiling, a copper kettle was boiling on the open fire and in a corner stood a massive bed with a patchwork quilt over it. (*PS, Ch 8, "The Potions Master"*)
- **rock cakes**

  > 'This is Ron,' Harry told Hagrid, who was pouring boiling water into a large teapot and putting rock cakes on to a plate. (*PS, Ch 8, "The Potions Master"*)
- **stoat sandwiches**

  > It was stiflingly hot inside. Even though it was such a warm day, there was a blazing fire in the grate. Hagrid made them tea and offered them stoat sandwiches, which they refused. (*PS, Ch 14, "Norbert the Norwegian Ridgeback"*)
- **peas**

  > Hagrid was sitting in an armchair outside his house; his trousers and sleeves were rolled up and he was shelling peas into a large bowl. ...
  >
  > Harry sank down next to the bowl of peas.
  > 'What did you talk to him about, Hagrid? Did you mention Hogwarts at all?' (*PS, Ch 16, Through the Trapdoor*)
- **possibly, chocolate frogs** - at least, Harry offered him one, though Hagrid got distracted before eating it by remembering Harry's present he made.

  > 'VOLDEMORT!' Harry bellowed, and Hagrid was so shocked, he stopped crying. 'I've met him and I'm calling him by his name. Please cheer up, Hagrid, we saved the Stone, it's gone, he can't use it. **Have a Chocolate Frog**, I've got loads...'
- **roosters** (presumably, it could have been for Fang, though)

  > 'Givin' me advice on gettin' kelpies out of a well,' growled Hagrid, moving a **half-plucked rooster off his scrubbed table** and setting down the teapot. 'Like I don' know. An' bangin' on about some Banshee he banished. If one word of it was true, I'll eat my **kettle**.'
  > *(CoS, Ch 7, "Mudbloods and Murmurs")*
- **kettles**??? (see the quote above)
- **treacle fudge and/or toffee**

  > 'He was the on'y man for the job,' said Hagrid, offering them a plate of treacle fudge,...
  >
  > Harry would have pointed out that trouble didn't come much worse than having slugs pouring out of your mouth, but he couldn't; Hagrid's treacle toffee had cemented his jaws together *(CoS, Ch 7, "Mudbloods and Murmurs")*
- **fruitcake**

  > He kept glancing nervously at the windows. He poured them both large mugs of boiling water (he had forgotten to add tea bags) and **was just putting a slab of fruitcake on a plate**, when there was a loud knock on the door. (*CoS, Ch14, "Cornelius Fudge"*)
- **Something resembling a beef casserole with a talon in it**. Ewwww.

  > They ended up having lunch with Hagrid, though they didn't eat much – Hagrid had made what he said was **a beef casserole, but after Hermione unearthed a large talon in hers, she, Harry and Ron rather lost their appetites**. They enjoyed themselves trying to make Hagrid tell them what the tasks in the Tournament were going to be, however, speculating which of the entrants were likely to be selected as champions, and wondering whether Fred and George were beardless yet. (*GoF, Chapter 15, "The Goblet of Fire"*)
- **doughy Biscuits** he ate with Madame Maxine

  > 'Dunno what yeh're talkin' about,' said Hagrid airily, fetching more cups from the dresser. **When he had made tea, and offered round a plate of doughy biscuits**, he leant back in his chair and surveyed Harry closely through his beetle-black eyes. (*GoF, Ch 37, "The Beginning"*)
- He does **NOT** eat Dragon steak :)

  > 'You're not going to eat that, are you, Hagrid?' said Ron, leaning in for a closer look. 'It looks poisonous.'
  > 'It's s'posed ter look like that, it's dragon meat,' Hagrid said. 'An' I didn' get it ter eat.' (*OotP, Ch 20, "Hagrids Tale"*)
- **Potatoes** (With Hagrid's bogies)

  > 'Hagrid,' said Hermione timidly, when he joined them at the table and started **peeling his potatoes** with a brutality that suggested that each tuber had done him a great personal wrong, 'we really wanted to carry on with Care of Magical Creatures, you know.' Hagrid gave another great snort. Harry rather thought some bogeys landed on the potatoes, and was inwardly thankful that they were not staying for dinner. (*HBP, Ch 11, "Hermione's Helping Hand"*)

---

- **Drinks**: Tea (PS), Strange amber liquid (PS), Wine (PS Xmas), Something from a goblet at welcome feast (PS, CoS), Eggnogg (CoS Xmas), Mulled Mead (PoA, Rosmerta's), Milk (in a jug, PoA, after Buckbeak lost an appeal), dandelion juice (OotP)

Comment: You "haven't the faintest idea what most of these foods are"??? Which ones?

Comment: [Humbugs](http://www.treasureislandsweets.co.uk/user/products/large/mint_humbugs__29215.jpg), [treacle toffee](https://www.johnsonstoffees.com/image/cache/catalog/toffee/treacle-toffee-700x518.jpg), [rock cakes](http://ozladym.com/recipes/RockCakes450.jpg), [stoat](http://www.factzoo.com/sites/all/img/mammals/weasel/stoat-grass.jpg) [sandwich](http://www.do-you-really-need-me-to-tell-you-what-a-sandwich-is-:-P)

Comment: Impressive +1. He also seems to eat whatever is served up in the great hall

Comment: @Au101 - If you can find evidence of him eating anything specific in the Great Hall - **please post!!** I couldn't find any quotes about him eating, just drinking

Comment: @DVK Clearly the reference to kettles is because he (and noone else) does eat kettles. It's very much like the phrase "if .... I'll eat my hat".

Comment: @ssmart *doesn't

Comment: In conclusion... he eats mostly what most people, especially on the countryside in colder climates, will eat. A bit more meat, casseroles, and stuff... he's just much less picky about the quality of the meals, which may be related to his giant blood - as long as it's not exactly poison, he'll eat it, disgusting or not.